# How to preserve the whitespaces between fields when using the "&" operator in sed

Tags: sed

Here is an example line that needs to be replaced

```
./some_file.c Fri Jan  6 17:24:13 MPST 2017
```

So after running sed to escape some of the characters in the original string, this is what I get

```
\.\/some_file\.c Fri Jan 6 17:24:13 MPST 2017
                        ^
                        1 less space
```

Here is my sed command in a bash script

```
local escaped_temp1=$(echo $temp1 | sed --regexp-extended 's/[\/&.]/\\&/g')
```

May I know how can I preserve the whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed doesn't remove the whitespace, `echo` with the unquoted argument does. Use `echo "$temp1"` instead:

```
$ temp1='./some_file.c Fri Jan  6 17:24:13 MPST 2017'
$ echo $temp1
./some_file.c Fri Jan 6 17:24:13 MPST 2017
$ echo "$temp1"
./some_file.c Fri Jan  6 17:24:13 MPST 2017
```

Side note: unless you actually want to replace `\` with `\\`, there is no need to escape `/` in the bracket expression. Also, you're not actually using an extended regex and don't need the `--regexp-extended`.

Comment: +1, was about to comment the same.. relevant...  [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)